# Alternative for SAP Business Objects with more features

Tags: data-visualization, rest, business-intelligence

I am currently looking for a business-layer-software or semantic-layer-software to replace SAP business objects. I am working for a data-management team for the public sector.
Do you have any recommendations for me that is not that costly as Denodo?
We need to meet the following three key requirements:

1. The software should be able to let the user and or developer to create "objects" stored in an order-like structure (explorer-like). These objects are dimensions or measures (column) of a fact table. As a user you can then combine several objects to let the software generate a table with the data in it. So in the background the software creates a specific sql query with joins based on a predefined model (relational, star, snowflake), executes this sql to a database-system like postgre and retrieves the data to display it to the user. The objects available should be searchable via a search function based on metadata of the objects.
2. The software should be able to manage permissions on what each user or user-group can or can not see. By "see" I mean: Being able to see the predefined objects available for them and also to only get the access to the data, which was previously granted to the user or user group.
3. The software should be able to deliver the data via a REST-API interface. The interface should be able to deliver a list of all granted objects for a specific user.

Thank you for helping me